# C#: Converting a collection into params[]

Tags: c#, string-formatting, parameters

Here is a simplification of my code:

```
void Foo(params object[] args)
{
    Bar(string.Format("Some {0} text {1} here {2}", /* I want to send args */);
}
```

`string.Format` requires the arguments sent as `params`. Is there some way I can convert the `args` collection into parameters for the `string.Format` method?

Comment: You didn't specify the type of args. Should be `params string[] args`. Other than that, you could just pass it as a normal array. `params` is just a compiler keyword that build an array from the sent parameters.

Comment: @HuBeZa: He specified the type: it is `object`. Why should he restrict himself to string parameters?

Comment: @Chris, something was wrong either with my browser or my eyes. I can swear it was `void Foo(params args[])`. I need a vacation :)

Comment: @HuBeZa Hehe, nothing's wrong with you, I made a mistake at first, and then I corrected it by editing the question :) But taking a vacation is always a good idea :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `params` keyword is only *syntactic sugar* that allows you to call such a method with any number of arguments. However, those arguments are always passed to the method as an array.

This means that `Foo(123, "hello", DateTime.Now)` is equivalent to `Foo(new object[] { 123, "hello", DateTime.Now })`.

You can therefore pass the arguments from `Foo` directly to `string.Format` like this:

```
void Foo(params object[] args)
{
  Bar(string.Format("Some {0} text {1} here {2}", args));
}
```

However, in this particular case, you demand three arguments (because you have {0}, {1} and {2} in your format). Therefore you should change your code to:

```
void Foo(object arg0, object arg1, object arg2)
{
  Bar(string.Format("Some {0} text {1} here {2}", arg0, arg1, arg2));
}
```

...or do as Marcelo suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Pass them in as a single argument:

```
Bar(string.Format("Some {0} text {1} here {2}", args));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using object.GetType(), for example

```
void Foo(params object[] args)
    {
        List<string> argStrings = new List<string>();

        foreach (object arg in args)
        {
            if (args.GetType().Name == typeof(String).Name)
            {
                argStrings.Add((string)arg);
            }
            else if (args.GetType().Name == typeof(DateTime).Name)
            {
                DateTime dateArg = (DateTime)arg;
                argStrings.Add(dateArg.ToShortDateString());
            }
            else
            {
                argStrings.Add(arg.ToString());
            }
        }

        Bar(string.Format("Some {0} text {1} here {2}", argStrings.ToArray()));
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with what I asked, but thank you for trying. By the way, there's no need to compare type names, you can just check `if (arg is DateTime)` etc.